# Fetching Data Tables

Tags: python, pandas, urllib, python-3.5

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://pakstockexchange.com/stock2/index_new.php?section=research&page=show_price_table_new&symbol=ABOT') as response:
        html=respnse.read()

import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_html('https://pakstockexchange.com/stock2/index_new.php?section=research&page=show_price_table_new&symbol=ABOT')
print(df)
```

I've used two different codes to fetch data table from a website were data is available for free. But every time I run my program I get the following error 'urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden'. Moreover the links seems to be working fine from a browser. Any idea how to solve this issue?

PS: Data can be seen without authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the server is raising a 301, exactly, but in general using `urllib` directly for a high level request like this is discouraged. You should use the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) package instead.

The equivalent `requests` fetch:

```
r = requests.get("https://pakstockexchange.com/stock2/index_new.php?section=research&page=show_price_table_new&symbol=ABOT")
```

Works fine.

```
r.status_code == 200
True
```

Comment: Pretty much gives me what I want. But how do I make it to just read the data table rather than the entire page.

Comment: That is a separate (and more difficult) question. The page you're linking to loads a bunch of JavaScript, which *then* loads the actual table. That is, the table isn't published as HTML itself...reading this would require a combination of [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) and [`pandas.read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.read_html.html). Are you sure there isn't an easier source for this data elsewhere?

Comment: No. Seems like I need to start learning selenium and figure out how can it help me with my solution. Anyways thanks for the answer. Solved one part of problem.